# Get Boolean Value and use it in Ajax call to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have this javascript code to call a function from my controller that returns a boolean value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function NumberAmt() {

           $.ajax({
                url: 'CallCenter/CallCenterAmt',
                type: 'Get',
                contentType: 'application/json;',
                success: function (data) {                       
                }         

            });

        })            
    });
```

I want to be able to use that boolean value in a function in the javascript on my page load to figure out what to display from my view. Please help Thanks

THis is the Controller Function it is calling

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CallCenterAmt()
    {
        bool threeNumbers=false;
        try
        {
            using (var entities = new OpenRoad.Data.Repository.OpenRoadEntities())
            {
                var CallCenterNumberAmt = (from c in entities.CallCenterNumberAmts
                                           where c.SiteId == OpenRoad.Web.Session.SiteId
                                           select c).FirstOrDefault();
                if (CallCenterNumberAmt == null)
                {                       
                        CallCenterNumberAmt = new Data.Repository.CallCenterNumberAmt();

                        CallCenterNumberAmt.SiteId = OpenRoad.Web.Session.SiteId;
                        CallCenterNumberAmt.ThreeNumbers = false;
                        entities.CallCenterNumberAmts.Add(CallCenterNumberAmt);
                        entities.SaveChanges();                        
                }
                else
                {
                    if (CallCenterNumberAmt.ThreeNumbers == true)
                    {
                        threeNumbers= true;
                    }
                    else
                        threeNumbers= false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return Json(threeNumbers);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the value get into the response?

Comment: Can you please explain what is that thing that returns a boolean value?

Comment: Where are you calling `NumberAmt()` from?

Comment: You're unnecessarily wrapping your code in two document ready blocks, only one is necessary. A shorthand way to write `$(document).ready(callbackFunction);` is `$(callbackFunction);`. See [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). You also don't need to give your function a name unless you intend on calling it elsewhere. Simply saying `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or `$(function() {...});` would be sufficient. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) explains more about JavaScript functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` should contain the value.  You need to make sure you're actually returning JSON, then call it based on the variable

e.g. `{YourVariable: true}`

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data.YourVariable) {
    //true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the Controller method returning a boolean, have it return a JSON object containing a boolean instead.

i.e. `{ isOkay : true }`

Then in your Ajax call, you can check to make sure that the controller returned what you thought it did by using `data.hasOwnProperty("isOkay")` and then using the value of `isOkay` to determine whatever else you need to.